Hydration error when installing NextJS 15
Well as title says. I do a "npx create-next-app@latest", since yesterday NextJS 15 got released, it installs next version 15.1.2. Now when I run "npm run dev". I go to localhost:3000 it says Hydration error by default and I didn't modify anything.
full error
Console Error
Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client. As a result 
this tree will be regenerated on the client. This can happen if a SSR-ed Client 
Component used

- A server/client branch `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`.
- Variable input such as `Date.now()` or `Math.random()` which changes each time it's 
called.
- Date formatting in a user's locale which doesn't match the server.
- External changing data without sending a snapshot of it along with the HTML.
- Invalid HTML tag nesting.

It can also happen if the client has a browser extension installed which messes with 
the HTML before React loaded.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error


- cz-shortcut-listen="true"

I tried this,
<html lang='en' suppressHydrationWarning>

it not worked. any solution for this?
My Project -
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^19.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^19.0.0",
    "next": "15.1.2"
  },

